# Objective C, Memory leaking?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary  *)attributeDict{

    //currentElenet is NSString
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"struct"]) {      

        self.post = [[Question alloc] init];

    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser  *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString  *)string{

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
        post.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", post.text, string];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"struct"]) {

        [conversations addObject:post];
        [post release];
        post = nil;
    }
}

//Question.m file
 @synthesize text

-(id)init{

    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil) {

    }
    else {
            //declared as retain in .h file
        text = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@""];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [title release];
}
```

Do you guys see any memory leaking here? I call NSXML delegate methods and it basically put an instance of "Question" into NSMutableArray. I checked instrument and there is a memory leak while parsing it. But I don't see why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentElement = [elementName copy];`

Please read the `copy` API's description in the documentation. There it is mentioned that

`this method retains the new object before returning it. The invoker of the method, however, is responsible for releasing the returned object.`

Answer (score 1):

You really need to include your property declarations in order for people to answer a memory management question with surety (since the properties define how the memory is managed), but assuming all `retain` properties:

- `currentElement` never appears to be released
- `text` appears never to be released
- `self.post` is assigned the result of `[[Question alloc] init]`. The result of that method is already an object you own, and the `post` setter retains it again. It should be released before the method exits, along the lines of:

  ```
  id question = [[Question alloc] init];
  self.post = question;
  [question release];
  ```

  (It should also be released in `dealloc` or when you're done with it to balance the setter)

Answer (score 0):

currentElement --- is not getting released in your parsing flow ... rest of the code looks correct